# cefsharp location change event C#

Tags: c#, cefsharp

i need to know how can set event when location of web view changed on cefsharp
and how can prevent not redirect to other url

```
        BrowserSettings browserSettings = new BrowserSettings();
        browserSettings.FileAccessFromFileUrlsAllowed = true;
        browserSettings.UniversalAccessFromFileUrlsAllowed = true;
        browserSettings.TextAreaResizeDisabled = true;
        WebView web_view;
        web_view = new WebView("http://google.com", browserSettings);
        web_view.LocationChanged += ??`enter code here`
        web_view.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        this.Controls.Add(web_view);
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you need to provide an implementation of the `IRequestHandler` interface. See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/CefSharp1/CefSharp.Example/ExamplePresenter.cs#L263 
If you return `true` you will block navigation.

The `LocationChanged` event you are talking about is not related to CefSharp web navigation. If you google for ["LocationChanged event"](http://google.com?q=locationchanged+event) it will probably leave a smile on your face :)

Comment: As far as I can see the `IRequest` parameter in `OnBeforeBrowse` only gives you the original URL requested.  If a redirection happens, the `isRedirect` parameter is set on the redirected request, but the request URL is still that of the original request, not the URL being redirected to.